# User in admin group still being prompted for password to sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo

I'm trying to script the creation of a user with `sudo` access for my ec2 instances.

I'm having problems setting up sudo access. I'm running the following as root...

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" testuser
usermod -a -G admin,sudo testuser
```

I then copy the authorized_keys from s3.

The ssh works fine at this point.

However if I try to sudo, I'm prompted for a password.

My sudoers file includes the following...

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Apart from logging out and logging back in, is there anything I need to do to actually make my changes take effect?

I didn't change the sudoers file, this was the default setup.

Also there's another system created user `ubuntu`, which can sudo successfully. However there is no explicit mention of this user in the `sudoers` file, so it must be doing it through group membership.

update: I tried adding every other group that "ubuntu" belongs to testuser, but I'm still being prompted for the password.

Is there any way I can figure out how "ubuntu" gets passwordless sudo access?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will always be prompted for a password unless you have the `NOPASSWD` option set in the `sudoers` file for any given entry (ignoring the grace period the password is remembered and hence not prompted, default 15 minutes).

For example, to make all members of the `sudo` group to have passwordless `sudo` implementation:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This indicates any member of the `sudo` group can run any command starting with `sudo` without prompting for password.

Similarly for user `foobar` to run the command `reboot`:

```
foobar ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

Note that, it is not a good idea to have passwordless `sudo` access for all commands unless you have a very good reason, you should consider restricting the commands to a necessary minimum.

---

The `sudo` rules can also be defined in files under the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, default `/etc/sudoers` file contains:

```
includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

at the end, this makes any file that does not contain `.` or ends in `~` to be read for `sudo` rules. Presumably the definitions for user `ubuntu` defined in any of the files under the `/etc/sudoes.d/` directory.

Comment: This is what I thought, but somehow the "ubuntu" user is able to do it. I'm not prompted for a password, and there is no specific entry for this user in sudoers.

Comment: @user1751825 Check `id ubuntu`

Comment: I haven't modified the sudoers file at all. If at all possible I'd like to keep everything as standard as possible.

Comment: @user1751825 Check also the files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, its probably defined in any of those files.

Comment: That was it. I don't know how I didn't think of that. There is a file in /etc/init.d/ that does it.

Comment: @user1751825 I have elaborated the answer..please check..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, on an AWS EC2 instance. Turns out that cloud-init adds a file in /etc/sudoers.d  `90-cloud-init-users` with these contents:

```
# Created by cloud-init v. 19.2-36-g059d049c-0ubuntu2~18.04.1 on Wed, 05 Jan 2022 09:44:40 +0000

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Adding the same line for my user solved the issue.

Since you mentioned S3 i guess this is your issue, combined with the behaviour of the sudoers config file: "     When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the      most specific match).", see `man sudo`.